# unzip csv file from url in google sheets

Tags: csv, url, google-apps-script, google-sheets, unzip

I need to unzip a zip file from a url containing a CSV and post it in a sheet, but I'm having problems.
I have tried with scripts such as following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var url = 'my URL' 
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob(); 
var zip = Utilities.zip([blob], "my.zip");
var files = Utilities.unzip(zip);
var unzipstr = files[0].getDataAsString();
var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(unzipstr);

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1");
ss.getRange(1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv);
  
}
```

I really hope some of you can help solve this on! I'm open for all ideas

Answer (score 1):

From what I've understood, the file in your URL is already a zip file and you are trying to zip a zip file here:

```
var zip = Utilities.zip([blob], "my.zip");
```

Remove the zip part of your code and your code should look like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = 'my URL' 
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  var file = Utilities.unzip(blob);
  var unzipstr = file[0].getDataAsString();
  var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(unzipstr);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1");
  ss.getRange(1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv);
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping me out Nikko! Unfortunately I get "Exception: Invalid argument (line 4, file "Code")". It seems like "var file = Utilities.unzip(blob);" is causing the problem - I have encountered this before and I'm not sure what to do about it. Do you have a solution?

Comment: The blob contentType should be `application/zip`. You can verify that by appending `Logger.log(blob.getContentType());`. If the result is not `application/zip`, you can change the contentType by adding this `blob.setContentType("application/zip");`

Comment: That worked! Many many thanks Nikko - this really helped me in my work!